# Bitnami wordpress install cannot locate wordpress DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, bitnami

We have a Bitnami Wordpress stack installed on one of our Windows servers.

The Wordpress install is working fine, AFAICT.

I need to export the SQL from the DB, so I went to the Bitnami phpmyadmin, by clicking the button in the Bitnami Manager app, which opens Firefox with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/phpmyadmin`

However, all I see in the list of databases are the phpmyadmin defaults: information_schema and test.

The wp-config file says the db is called `bitnami_wordpress`.

But I can't figure out why this DB is not in the list.  Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turned out that accessing the phpmyadmin via a browser on my computer was not sufficient.  I needed to access the **actual computer** the server was running on.

So I needed to use Remote Desktop to access the PC, open a browser there, access phpmyadmin and then all the DBs appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to the same issue. The answer is in your wp-config.php
'DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress'
'DB_PASSWORD', '********'

Hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect login. Not using the root login for phpmyadmin.

Possibly also seeing "no privilege to create new database" error.

Options to try are "root" for both user and password. "user" for user. "bitnami" for password or "user" or "root" for username, along with a password you may have setup during install.

I know it's a few days since you posted and you've probably figured it out however i had the same issue and came back to post an answer for any future google searchers.